# Triangle with same background-image ::after

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/u2DAr/1/

I simply want to 'reverse' that triangle before the section. An upside down triangle within the background-image from `<header>`.

I've tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/u2DAr/2/
but it doesn't continue the same background from `<header>`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the `background-position` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/u2DAr/4/

I couldn't think of a way to do it with the existing html, I had to add two `div` to the `header`.

I added two white bars to the bottom of the header to block out the bottom part of the image that will never be seen. I placed the `before` and `after` squares in the bottom middle where the arrow should be, then rotated them 45 degrees to form an arrow "gap" so the image can peek through.

```
header:before, header:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    top:100%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-30px) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    transform:translateY(-30px) rotate(45deg);
    z-index:1;
}

header:before {
    left:calc(50% - 25px);
}

header:after {
    left:calc(50% + 25px);
}

.white {
    background:#f5f5f5;
    width:calc(50% - 25px);
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    border-color:orange;
}

.white.left {
    left:0;
}

.white.right {
    right:0;
}
```